# Making a content feed

Tags: rss, feed

I am making a website which allows people to discuss news topics. I was looking to make like a news feed which shows the most talked about topics and topics followed by users however I am not sure how to do this? As in I can't think of a process to do this and I don't think Rss feed's are the answer, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any idea how will users be using the feed?

Comment: Yes, the users will basically be supplied with the top viewed topics/news topics and essentially it will just be links with images and small amount of details.  When clicked, it will take the user to the link with the topic, etc.(Does that answer the question?) I suppose RSS may be worth looking into?

Comment: Not really. I mean, will be user reading the feed with a browser or something?

Comment: Well it's almost like facebook, when the user logs in, they will be displayed with a feed. So yeah, with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I am developing a website too and learning how to develop an RSS engine of my own. 
http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/help/rss/default.stm#mysite
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-RSS-Feed
But I need more information. What I know is- RSS feeder itself searches for latest content on the news websites or blogs (by looking at their dates perhaps) and it places the latest post on top. Now the problem is that I am not able to create that. I need to know a lot about RSS and specially XML.
But your problem is different I think. You want to show the trending post on the top. Then, I think you will need to create an algorithm to rank your pages/posts. And this algorithm should evaluate the real hotness of the content. For example a 20 days old post on your website might still be hotter than latest trending news and it might be searched in the top news.
But now the question is how would this algorithm decide whether a post hot or not? Well this can be done on the basis of likes or hearts give to it by users, comments on the page, links in the comments on the page, shares (you can track that), and external links to your post etc etc. Now it's up to you what you will prefer to make your post trending. You can give more weightage to external links or maybe comments or you could set limits to all of these which when reach gives a sign of full success of the post.
 
Sorry If you don't get it. I was just thinking of the solutions. I really don't know the solution to it already.